# Android - MediaPlayer/SoundPool performance?

Tags: android, performance, android-mediaplayer, soundpool

I'm new to Android and I have built a 16-Step-Pattern-Sequencer. I have done this with MediaPlayer, but when more than 1 Sound should be played at the same time, it all slows down :/ .. so I  tried the same with SoundPool (which is marked as deprecated) but the same effect appears here, too..

It is built like:
- every Step, I check if a note is set.. if so.. the sound is played
- the 16-Step-Loop runs in a Thread

After long testing, it seems like the first run-through (all 16 steps) is all at normal speed.. with the beginning of the second run-through it all is slowed down according to how much sounds have to be played .. :/

is there a other solution i could try?

EDIT:

this is the code for my sequencer

Initialization:

```
    soundPool = new SoundPool(32, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
            loaded = true;
        }
    });
    soundID_kick_1 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.kick1, 1);
    soundID_kick_2 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.kick2, 1);
    soundID_kick_3 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.kick3, 1);
    soundID_kick_4 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.kick4, 1);
    soundID_kick_5 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.kick5, 1);
    soundID_kick_6 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.kick6, 1);
    soundID_kick_7 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.kick7, 1);
    soundID_kick_8 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.kick8, 1);
    soundID_hh_1 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.hh1, 2);
    soundID_hh_2 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.hh2, 2);
    soundID_hh_3 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.hh3, 2);
    soundID_hh_4 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.hh4, 2);
    soundID_hh_5 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.hh5, 2);
    soundID_hh_6 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.hh6, 2);
    soundID_hh_7 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.hh7, 2);
    soundID_hh_8 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.hh8, 2);
    soundID_sd_1 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.sd1, 3);
    soundID_sd_2 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.sd2, 3);
    soundID_sd_3 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.sd3, 3);
    soundID_sd_4 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.sd4, 3);
    soundID_sd_5 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.sd5, 3);
    soundID_sd_6 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.sd6, 3);
    soundID_sd_7 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.sd7, 3);
    soundID_sd_8 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.sd8, 3);
    soundID_snd_1 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.snd1, 4);
    soundID_snd_2 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.snd2, 4);
    soundID_snd_3 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.snd3, 4);
    soundID_snd_4 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.snd4, 4);
    soundID_snd_5 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.snd5, 4);
    soundID_snd_6 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.snd6, 4);
    soundID_snd_7 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.snd7, 4);
    soundID_snd_8 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.snd8, 4);
```

later the sequencer runs when seqPlay is clicked:

```
private View.OnClickListener seqPlay = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        btn_seq_play = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_seq_play);
        Thread seq_thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Do loop while seq_status==true
                while(seq_status) {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++) { 
                        // Play Kicks if set
                        Log.i("Durchlauf Kicks" + i, "seqKick_status[i] " + seqKick_status[i]);
                        if (seqKick_status[i] != 0 && !mute_kick_status) {
                            switch (seqKick_status[i]) {
                                case 1: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_kick_1, volKick[i], volKick[i], 1, 0, 1f);                                       
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 2: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_kick_2, volKick[i], volKick[i], 1, 0, 1f);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 3: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_kick_3, volKick[i], volKick[i], 1, 0, 1f);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 4: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_kick_4, volKick[i], volKick[i], 1, 0, 1f);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 5: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_kick_5, volKick[i], volKick[i], 1, 0, 1f);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 6: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_kick_6, volKick[i], volKick[i], 1, 0, 1f);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 7: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_kick_7, volKick[i], volKick[i], 1, 0, 1f);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 8: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_kick_8, volKick[i], volKick[i], 1, 0, 1f);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        // Play HH if set
                        Log.i("Durchlauf HH" + i, "seqHH_status[i] " + seqHH_status[i]);
                        if (seqHH_status[i] != 0 && !mute_hh_status) {
                            switch (seqHH_status[i]) {
                                case 1: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_hh_1, volHH[i], volHH[i], 1, 0, 1f);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 2: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_hh_2, volHH[i], volHH[i], 1, 0, 1f);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 3: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_hh_3, volHH[i], volHH[i], 1, 0, 1f);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 4: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_hh_4, volHH[i], volHH[i], 1, 0, 1f);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 5: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_hh_5, volHH[i], volHH[i], 1, 0, 1f);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 6: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_hh_6, volHH[i], volHH[i], 1, 0, 1f);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 7: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_hh_7, volHH[i], volHH[i], 1, 0, 1f);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 8: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_hh_8, volHH[i], volHH[i], 1, 0, 1f);
                                    break;
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        // Play SD if set
                        Log.i("Durchlauf SD" + i, "seqSD_status[i] " + seqSD_status[i]);
                        if (seqSD_status[i] != 0 && !mute_sd_status) {
                            switch (seqSD_status[i]) {
                                case 1: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_sd_1, volSD[i], volSD[i], 1, 0, 1f);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 2: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_sd_2, volSD[i], volSD[i], 1, 0, 1f);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 3: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_sd_3, volSD[i], volSD[i], 1, 0, 1f);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 4: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_sd_4, volSD[i], volSD[i], 1, 0, 1f);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 5: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_sd_5, volSD[i], volSD[i], 1, 0, 1f);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 6: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_sd_6, volSD[i], volSD[i], 1, 0, 1f);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 7: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_sd_7, volSD[i], volSD[i], 1, 0, 1f);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 8: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_sd_8, volSD[i], volSD[i], 1, 0, 1f);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        // Play SND if set
                        Log.i("Durchlauf SND" + i, "seqSND_status[i] " + seqSND_status[i]);
                        if (seqSND_status[i] != 0 && !mute_snd_status) {
                            switch (seqSND_status[i]) {
                                case 1: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_snd_1, volSND[i], volSND[i], 1, 0, 1f);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 2: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_snd_2, volSND[i], volSND[i], 1, 0, 1f);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 3: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_snd_3, volSND[i], volSND[i], 1, 0, 1f);                                        
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 4: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_snd_4, volSND[i], volSND[i], 1, 0, 1f);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 5: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_snd_5, volSND[i], volSND[i], 1, 0, 1f);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 6: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_snd_6, volSND[i], volSND[i], 1, 0, 1f);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 7: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_snd_7, volSND[i], volSND[i], 1, 0, 1f);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 8: {
                                    soundPool.play(soundID_snd_8, volSND[i], volSND[i], 1, 0, 1f);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // KICK-SEQ
        if(seq_status) {
            btn_seq_play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
            seq_status = false;
            seq_thread.interrupt();
        } else {
            btn_seq_play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stop);
            seq_status = true;
            seq_thread.start();
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the length of the audiofile.
Long Music files that are not so big that you can keep in memory are suitable for media player. 
Short sound of 0.02-5 seconds: soundprool

And there is also Audiotrack for streaming files but a bit more complicated to implement.

Try this...or Show us the crucial parts of the code maybe you meesed up or so like doing the calls from within the main thread or sth like that

edit:my code suggestion:

```
private View.OnClickListener seqPlay = new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    btn_seq_play = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_seq_play);
    if(!seq_Status)
    {
        Thread seq_thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do loop while seq_status==true
            ...
        }

        btn_seq_play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stop);
        seq_Thread.start();
        }
    else
        btn_seq_play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);


    seq_Status=!seq_Status;

    }
}
```

now your thread will die with a maximum reaction of 100ms by the next time he get to the beginning of the while loop and checks that seq_Status has changed to false...and i think its ok to do that

you could do an if before he sleeps to check wether seq_Status has changed to catch it before it gets to sleep of course

Comment: Hello from Berlin; ) Could you provide the initialisation of your soundproof. How many maximum stream did you tell him to use.

Comment: Hey Ilja :) .. I uodated the thread above with the initialisation.. there is a total of 32 samples that can be set into 4 sequencer-tracks (each 8 samples)

Comment: Ok I see there no false code...except that you take it for granted that your sounds are loaded but ok thats not that important at this time as long as you are sure every sound has been loaded ... I ussually have for every sound a boolean what i set if the sound has been loaded correctly but its ok the soundpool dont mind if you play a sound thats not loaded unlike mediaplayer.... the deprication is onlyy beginning at Android L so dont mind that(google got the Idea to use a Builder for that instead of a constructor)....nevertheless i have no solution for your issue the code looks fine so far

Comment: one thing....when you load the sound...in the docs is it said that the priority flag(the last parameter) should be set to 1 for future ompatability and that it has no effect atm

Comment: thank you anyway for taking a look at my problem and my code ;)

Comment: no problem...did you try setting the priority to 1 on the load() mehtod?

Comment: and one thing: your onclick is a bit strange you declare a thread to be started and it gets startted at first time you cli k the button...then on second click you make another thread...while the old one continues and because seq_status is false the thread just dies...and the thread you just created by clicking stop gets interrupted although it hasnt started allready...so oyu have here many threads that are garbage collected when you press the stop button make sure only to create a thread when you press start...

Comment: I had it all set to priority 1 first, then i played around hoping it would solve the probem :) .

Comment: thanks for the tip :) .. you mean i should ask.. in the onClick first if (seq_thread != null) ?? .. and only create a new Thread if this is false? .. otherwise juste start the previous one?

Comment: seq_Thread is allways null because you declare it locally and its invisible to the outside of the method. I would rather do sth like this:

Comment: and yeah since this thread object is a local one it makes no sense to interrupt it because everytime you leave your onclick method your reference get lsot but the thread is still running (maybe)...but you have well no reference...all you have is the reference to antoher thread that you intialize everytime from scratch

Comment: edited my answer with my suggestion for a cleaner code facing the issue i described

Comment: Thanks for the advice :)  .. i have changed the code.. unfortunately the problem still appears :/

Comment: mmmh very strange behaviour...either you could try and make all the sound a little bit longer...I had an issue where my sounds happen to be only a few ms long...or try to set the stream of the soundpool to more then 32 maybe 128 or so...does the logcat give you error from audiotrack with a -12 code and say sound couldnt be loaded or so?

Comment: I assume you dont create the soundpool everytime new inside the activity and not releasing it?!

Comment: I have tried to set the streams to 128 and 264 .. with no effect.. i will try now to use some other (longer) samples.. the soundpool is created once in the onCreate and I dont release any of the samples loaded